# Could be filtered the subquery based on the main query? (Graphql)

Tags: graphql, prisma

I would like to filter the sub query based on the result of the main query, my query is

```
{
  users(where: { id:"server1"  }) {
    id
    name
    lastMonthPaid  <-----------I want to used this variable in sub query
    offers{
      books (where:{date: lastMonthPaid}){<----------this is the sub query
        dealprice
      }
    }
  }
}
```

By the way I use prisma
So, does Graphql provide mechanism to do this kind of Query?

Comment: It is not possible to achieve this with Prisma.